# Impersonation Problem

Tags: wcf

How can I Impersonate a User that is Login in the client in my service?
I use ADMembershipProvider in wcf Service.

Comment: You have to give us a lot more information. At  the moment we can only guess what  your question is.

Answer (score 0):

How does the client log in?

In order to impersonate programmatically, you need a "WindowsPrincipal", which you ordinarily construct with the a logon "token".  You get the token by using the Win32 LogonUser function.

I've used ADMembershipProvider with ASP.net and discovered that I cannot simply use the identity that it ties to the page variable.  It is not a WindowsPrincipal.  However, in response to a question I asked recently on Stack Overflow about Windows Identity Foundation, I received information about c2WTS, which takes a Windows Claims Identity and converts it to a token.

I have not used this program yet, but I hope this helps you accomplish your goals.